# Google Spreadsheet service Using OAuth 2.0 - C#

Tags: c#, authentication, google-sheets, .net-4.5, google-sheets-api

I'm facing an issue with Google Spreadsheet service. Previously I used below code to call my spreadsheet then retrieve data and save into my local database.

```
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadSheet");
service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);


string token = service.QueryClientLoginToken(); // Now 404 error
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

foreach (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet in feed.Entries){
// Retrieve data and save into my local machng
}
```

Once google disable **OAuth1.0** I got 404 error."
Previously I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api).

I already have project in [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/)  And I created my *client Id* as *service account* .

How Can I modify my code ?

I have to use google spreedsheet service of r my task.

Appreciate your answers/ feedback's

Comment: Having the same issue.  Please post something if you find a workaround.

Comment: you can try this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469058/google-gdata-client-gdatarequestexception-authentication-suddenly-fails-in-old/30497154#30497154

but this is not work for me.. Because in my case is different

Comment: developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize 

**Important: OAuth 1.0 is no longer supported and will be disabled on May 5, 2015. If your application uses OAuth 1.0, you must migrate to OAuth 2.0 or your application will cease functioning.**